# Confirmation on multiple buttons in django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

In my django template, I have a block of code which looks as follow:

```
{% block b %}
    { % for foo in foos %}
        { % if foo.some_variable % }            
            <form method="LINK" action="{% url "some_view" foo.id %}" id="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Button"/></form>
        { % else % }
            <form method="LINK" action="{% url "some_view1" foo.id %}" id="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Button1"/></form>  
            <form method="LINK" action="{% url "some_view2" foo.id %}" id="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Button2"/></form>      
        { % endif %}
        <br>
     { % endfor %}
{% endblock % }
```

I need to make confirmation popup for all of those buttons.  So I tried to add

```
onclick = "return confirm("are u sure?")"
```

And it works, but it's ugly. I want to add custom buttons names, header and so on. 
So I read that this is not possible in clear javascript and I should use jquery.

I tried something like this, but since I don't know jquery neither js it doesn't work:

```
<script>
    function confirmAction(){
        var confirmed ; 
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {
                    confirmed = true;
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                },

                "No": function() {
                    confirmed = false;
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                }
            }
        });
        return confirmed
    }
</script>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Are you sure??">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        Are you sure you want to do this?</p>
</div>
```

When I click on button, popup appears, but it suddenly disappears and I'm redirected to a view anyway.

Could you try to help me?
Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

confirmed is always false because javascript is asynchrone.

You need to use some closure. Something like this should do the trick:

```
    $('input:submit').click(function() {
        // get form associated with the button
        var form = $(this).parents('form')
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    // maybe set an hidden field to keep button value if needed
                    form.submit()
                },

                "No": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: How to run it? Should I delete "onclick" in form and just paste your code?

Comment: Yes, it's always better to use jquery to bind some events instead of the onclick attribute. $(selector).click(function(){}) or $(selector).on('click', function(){}). But this code need to run after the DOM is loaded. You can wrap this snippet in $(document).ready(function() {}) or just put the <script/> tag at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yeah, I know about <script> tags ;). It works fine. But how do I make 'dialog-confirm' appear in popup, not in the bottom of my site? And I need different confirmation message for each button type, how do I do that?

Comment: This is another problem. I guess you need to include jquery.ui stylesheets in your html code or use your own css to make this work

Comment: You're now talking about making 'dialog-confirm' appears in popup or about the different confirm messages? I tried to follow this example Actually I was studying this example : http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation and I pasted two lines of code ('<link rel = blah blah >). Shouldn't it do the trick? Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: That's about the popup. If you need different messages just store them in the form with a class="dialog" and use $('.dialog', form).dialog()

Comment: So shouldn't using their stylesheets do the trick? 'Are you sure you want to do this?' - this is still out of popup. Title is in the popup.

Comment: Ok, so message is actually in popup, but also on bottom of my page. How can I fix it? And could you tell me something more about setting those different messages?

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is that I also have other buttons designed this way (form, submit) on my site.
But I've got it work with this piece of code:

```
<script>
     $('.popup_button').click(function() {
         // get form associated with the button
         var form = $(this)

         $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
             resizable: false,
             height:200,
             modal: true,
             buttons: {
                 "Yes": function() {
                     $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                     form.submit()
                 },

                 "No": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                 }
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
</script>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirmation" style='display: none'>
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

So confirmation popup appears only for those buttons, which have class 'popup_button'.
The only thing I'm missing is how t get custom confirmation message for each button.

When I substitute

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog
```

with

```
$(".new_button_class").dialog
```

and then add class='new_button_class' and 'title' attributes to my button forms, strange things happen. What is more, I don't now how to set dialog message this way.

adding

```
$(".new_button_class", form).dialog
```

instead causes popups not to appear at all.

How to fix it?